# I'm unsure what's wrong when I declare these variables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following code:

```
USE pricingdb
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.Events_060107_2012
(
    Date_Time varchar(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Event_Type TEXT,
    Month_of_Year TEXT,
    Survey DOUBLE,
    Actual DOUBLE,
    Prior_Data DOUBLE,
    Revised DOUBLE,
    Relevance FLOAT,
    Ticker TEXT
);
```

Go

And I'm getting an Error:

```
"Incorrect syntax near ','.  Level 15, State 1, Line 6"
```

I'm aware that this should be a pretty easy problem to fix, but for whatever reason I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how to go about fixing this.  My knowledge of SQL is beginner at best, so most of the other threads I read were a little above my head.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

DOUBLE is not a valid datatype in sql server

Use float, numeric, ... or any of the other types that are supported.

More info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx

Comment: As an aside while text is valid it's [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Use decimal or numeric and specify the places. Float is an inexact number and can cause rounding issues and should be avoided.

Comment: Please use varchar(max) or nvarchar(Max) instead of text.

Comment: And using `varchar` for a column called `Date_Time` looks suspicious, why not use the `datetime` data type?

Answer (score 1):

Two issues. The first is that there is no datatype of double. The second is that float takes a size to indicate the difference in precision. An equivalent create query to the one above is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Events_060107_2012
(
    Date_Time varchar(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Event_Type TEXT,
    Month_of_Year TEXT,
    Survey FLOAT(53),
    Actual FLOAT(53),
    Prior_Data FLOAT(53),
    Revised FLOAT(53),
    Relevance FLOAT(24),
    Ticker TEXT
);
```

Comment: Doesn't really add anything of value to Buckley's answer. `FLOAT` without a size is treated as `FLOAT(53)` anyway. The only other precision supported is `float(24)` for which the synonym `REAL` can be used. Not sure why you decided to change `Relevance` from `float` to `real`.

Answer (score 0):

Use float instead of double (or decimal)

```
USE pricingdb
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.Events_060107_2012
(
Date_Time varchar(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
Event_Type TEXT,
Month_of_Year TEXT,
Survey FLOAT,
Actual FLOAT,
Prior_Data FLOAT,
Revised FLOAT,
Relevance FLOAT,
Ticker TEXT
);
```